# Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs, backbone.js

i am working on simple node js module ... 
 a module that, when i give an ID and a request rate, returns a readable stream which emits location data for the corresponding satellite...
 i am trying to implement by using sub classing ReadableStream

http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable

i am using this api

https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544

providing my code below..

http://jsfiddle.net/omb3rwqn/1/

```
var request = require('request');
var url = 'https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544'
var reader = request(url);
readable.on('readable', function() {

    console.log('got %d characters of string data');

})
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything with that "through" variable; the error message seems pretty clear. What do you expect the "request()" function to be?

Comment: @Pointy i am trying to achieve sth similar to thsi https://github.com/mikeal/request

Comment: Look at the very first line of code in the very first example! You have to import the code via `require()`.

Comment: @Pointy updated my code but still same error

Comment: Do you have the "request.js" library available on the machine you're using to test the code?  (Also I think you want `reader.on()` instead of `readable.on()`.)

Comment: @Pointy they have given as npm package only not sure how to include in fiidle https://www.npmjs.org/package/request

Answer (score -1):

did you on accident in your app.js end-point do

```
app.post('/api/v1/something',function(req,res)
{
    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];       
    **var a = request.connection.remoteAddress**
```

in which case the 'request' in your code is a red herring. what you are really looking for is the fact that your end-point defines 'req' (or anything other than request)